# How do we conclude that $h_c$ is non decreasing? A question concernig a paper from Varadhan (2003)

Tags: random-walk, large-deviation-theory

In the paper Large Deviations for Random Walks in a Random Environment (2003)

One reads on page 1226:

[image]

$h_c$ is obtained as the following limit:

$$h_c(y) = \lim_n \frac{1}{n} -\log \sup_m \big(\pi^m(\omega, 0,n y) e^{-c|m-n|}\big) $$

where $\pi^n(\omega, 0 , ny)$ is the probability of the random walk in the  environment $\omega$ leave the origin and reach the site ny in n steps.

[image]

To obtain that for $y \leq y'$ we have $h_c(y)\leq h_c(y')$ we compute 
$$h^n_c(y) = \frac{1}{n} -\log \sup_m \big(\pi^m(\omega, 0,n y) e^{-c|m-n|}\big) \\
 = \frac{1}{n} -\log  \big(\pi^{m(n,y)}(\omega, 0,n y) e^{-c|m(n,y)-n|}\big)$$

and we compare $$h^n_c(y') - h^n_c(y) = \frac{1}{n}\bigg[c|m(n,y') - n| - c | m(n,y)-n|  + \log \frac{\pi^{m(n,y)}(\omega, 0,n y)}{\pi^{m(n,y')}(\omega, 0, n y')}\bigg]$$

Heuristically one thinks that  if $y'> y$ then $m(n,y')\geq m(n,y)$ since it takes longer to leave 0 and reach $n y'$ therefore to conclude the comparison, we would need to decide what is the behavior of 
 $$\log \frac{\pi^{m(n,y)}(\omega, 0,n y)}{\pi^{m(n,y')}(\omega, 0, n y')} $$

Maybe we could find estimates on $\pi^{m(n,y)}(\omega, 0,n y)$ that would allow us to decide the sign of $h^n_c(y') - h^n_c(y)$.

Any ideas?